# Flutter: Loading an IFrame from WebView

Tags: android, webview, flutter

I am looking for a way to load an iFrame from Flutter WebView ( webview_flutter: ^0.1.2), and couldn't find any relevant info.

```
                 Container(
                    child: WebView(
                      initialUrl: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/abc',
                      javaScriptMode: JavaScriptMode.unrestricted,
                    )),
```

Any idea how to pass IFrame to Webview, will it be as part of initialUrl?, I have tried the same, but it didn't load properly.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This might do what you want

```
 Container(
    child: WebView(
      initialUrl: Uri.dataFromString('<html><body><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/abc"></iframe></body></html>', mimeType: 'text/html').toString(),
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
    )),
```

This passes a data URL that contains a HTML page with an iframe.

Comment: Sorry, don't know and won't have time for a closer look the next days.

Comment: This is what I call Gamer move

Comment: you guys figured this out? what link format are you using? i tried swapping embeded/ to watch?v?= but a big youtube bar shows up. and with embeded the fullscreen button and quality and speed settings don't show
ALSO. it's not showing ads, why?

Comment: This approach has some limitations. I don't remember details. Might be CORS-related. It's probably better to use a different approach as implementing a simple proxy in Dart inside your Flutter app where you serve a port and forward all requests and pass `http://localhost:1234` to webview where `1234` is the port you are serving. I don't have related code at hand.

Comment: I understood nothing of what you said sorry haha, what do you mean ports? 
all i want is to display youtube videos. just like the youtube app does it

Answer (score 5):

Based on @Günter above i had slight adjustments cause i couldnt get it to work on ios. This is based of the [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter#-example-tab-) official pub.dev page.

```
String html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
            <head>
            <style>
            body {
              overflow: hidden; 
            }
        .embed-youtube {
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
            padding-top: 0px;
            height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .embed-youtube iframe,
        .embed-youtube object,
        .embed-youtube embed {
            border: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        </style>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
           </head>
          <body bgcolor="#121212">                                    
        <div class="embed-youtube">
         <iframe
          id="vjs_video_3_Youtube_api"
          style="width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;position:absolute;"
          class="vjs-tech holds-the-iframe"
          frameborder="0"
          allowfullscreen="1"
          allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
          webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen
          title="Live Tv"
          frameborder="0"
          src="$iframeUrl"
          ></iframe></div>
          </body>                                    
        </html>
  """;
final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
    Completer<WebViewController>();
final String contentBase64 =
    base64Encode(const Utf8Encoder().convert(html));
return WebView(
  initialUrl: 'data:text/html;base64,$contentBase64',
  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
    _controller.complete(webViewController);
  },
  onPageStarted: (String url) {
    print('Page started loading: $url');
  },
  onPageFinished: (String url) {
    print('Page finished loading: $url');
  },
  gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
);
```

I then used @Lorenzo Pichilli answer to do it on android. I worked a bit faster for me. Hope this helps anyone. Took me a whole day.

**PS**

This has allowed me to play both youtube and vimeo videos on Android and iOS. Works okay so far

**EDIT:**

To add a loader before the webview finishes loading check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54698124/flutter-how-to-show-a-circularprogressindicator-before-webview-loads-de-page) on how to add a progress circular indicator