# Flutter: How to show a CircularProgressIndicator before WebView loads the page?

Tags: webview, flutter

I'm using the webview_fluttter plugin, but I can't find a way to show a CircularProgressIndicator before the webview shows the page...

What's the equivalent of Androids WebViewClient     onPageStarted/onPageFinished?

```html
WebView(
  initialUrl: url,
  onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
  },
)
```

Comment: Have you got it worked?

Comment: Unfortunately, with the official plugin from Google no. It's a shame Google didn't implement a so simple functionality.

Comment: You have to use Futurebuilder, Example- https://gist.github.com/iapicca/2aae10a174310422e3ec515234054793

Answer (score 28):

In version 0.3.5 there is 'onPageFinished' callback. You can create WebView container with IndexedStack.

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class _WebViewContainerState extends State < WebViewContainer > {
  var _url;
  final _key = UniqueKey();
  _WebViewContainerState(this._url);
  num _stackToView = 1;

  void _handleLoad(String value) {
    setState(() {
      _stackToView = 0;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _stackToView,
        children: [
          Column(
            children: < Widget > [
              Expanded(
                child: WebView(
                  key: _key,
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                  initialUrl: _url,
                  onPageFinished: _handleLoad,
                )
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}

class WebViewContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final url;
  WebViewContainer(this.url);
  @override
  createState() => _WebViewContainerState(this.url);
}
```

Comment: The 0.3.5 version worked on iOS, but on Android I got this error: Note: /Users/rlecheta/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-0.3.5+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/webviewflutter/FlutterWebViewClient.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Program type already present: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.

Comment: After upgrade the gradle version my project executed successfully. But when I try to use the WebView my app crashes. Just in Android. It works on iOS. You can see the full stack trace here: https://livecom-chat.s3.amazonaws.com/livecomProd/b1fb97f9-2bdb-47a6-af81-e9d8df766f94/1553263145031/webview_error.rtf

Comment: It`s hard to tell without looking at code. This code works on all my iOS/Android devices. Also, consider that this plugin is still in "Developers Preview", so it can be their bug.

Comment: although i get a starnge error where it is constantly rebuilding itself my bad, i fixed it

Comment: Work nicely. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

This is working properly for me

```
  initState() {
    isLoading = true;
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text("Your Title",centerTitle: true
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new WebView(
            initialUrl: /* YourUrl*/,
            onPageFinished: (_) {
              setState(() {
                isLoading = false;
              });
            },
          ),
          isLoading ? Center( child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : Container(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Isn't there a `)` missing behind `"Your Title"`?

Comment: I also think you need to add `super.initState();` to make the `initState()` function working.

Comment: Sorry for all the comments but it is also necessary to `@override` the `initState()` function.

Answer (score 13):

```
class _WebViewContainerState extends State<WebViewContainer> {
  var _url;
  final _key = UniqueKey();
  bool _isLoadingPage;

  Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();

  _WebViewContainerState(this._url);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isLoadingPage = true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new WebView(
            key: _key,
            initialUrl: _url,
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (webViewCreate) {
              _controller.complete(webViewCreate);
            },
            onPageFinished: (finish) {
              setState(() {
                _isLoadingPage = false;
              });
            },
          ),
          _isLoadingPage
              ? Container(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )
              : Container(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: y'r wlcome bro.

Comment: Can't interact with the web view anymore!

Answer (score 3):

Optional parameters hidden and initialChild are available so that you can show something else while waiting for the page to load.**If you set hidden to true it will show a default CircularProgressIndicator.** If you additionally specify a Widget for initialChild you can have it display whatever you like till page-load.

check this page : [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin)

and you can specify what you want to show with `initialChild`

```
return new MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter WebView Demo',
  theme: new ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  routes: {
    '/': (_) => const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter WebView Demo'),
    '/widget': (_) => new WebviewScaffold(
      url: selectedUrl,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: const Text('Widget webview'),
      ),
      withZoom: true,
      withLocalStorage: true,
      hidden: true,
      initialChild: Container(
        child: const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  },
);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, I'll try use your solution. But right now I'm using the official webview plugin from Google. I think it is missing this feature.

Comment: Hi @clipi onat, no because I'm using the "webview_flutter" plugin. But thank you for your help.

Comment: This is not a good solution for anyone trying to render a webview inline within the widget tree because flutter_webview_plugin uses an overlay.

Answer (score 1):

I use a combination of [webview_flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webview_flutter), [progress_indicators](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/progress_indicators)

Here is a sample working code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:progress_indicators/progress_indicators.dart';




class ContactUs extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ContactUsState createState() => _ContactUsState();
}

class _ContactUsState extends State<ContactUs> {

  bool vis1 = true;
  Size deviceSize;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    final lindicator = Center(
      child: AnimatedOpacity(
        // If the Widget should be visible, animate to 1.0 (fully visible). If
        // the Widget should be hidden, animate to 0.0 (invisible).
        opacity: vis1 ? 1.0 : 0.0,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        // The green box needs to be the child of the AnimatedOpacity
        child: HeartbeatProgressIndicator(
          child: Container(
            width: 100.0,
            height: 50.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(35.0,0.0,5.0,0.0),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.all_inclusive, color: Colors.white, size: 14.0,),
                Text(
                  "Loading View", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 6.0),),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Row(
            children:<Widget>[
              Text('THisApp'),
              lindicator,
            ]),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      body: new Container(
          child:WebView(
            initialUrl: 'https://cspydo.com.ng/',
            javaScriptMode: JavaScriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController){
              setState(() {
                vis1=false;
              });
            },
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but onWebViewCreated is called right in the beginning... I need to know when WebView finishes the page loading. I think the plugin is missing this functionality. What I need is exactly what onPageFinished of Android WebViewClient does.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.You can add **initialChild** and set attribute hidden as true.

```
WebviewScaffold(
hidden: true,
  url:url,initialChild: Center(
 child: Text("Plase Wait...",style: TextStyle(
  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent[100]
  ),)
 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work on isLoading and change it after you are sure data is loaded properly.

```
    class X extends StatefulWidget {
      XState createState() => XState();
    }
    class XState extends State<X>{

    bool isLoading = false;

    @override
      void initState() {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = true;
        });
        super.initState();
      }

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                  isLoading ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : WebView(...)
              ]
            )
          );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that I can't find a way to know when webviews finishes the page loading..

Comment: You can use flutter_native_web [https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_native_web] @rlecheta

Comment: Just tried this myself, the webview will never render.

Comment: Back here again, I just want to point out that this logic makes no sense. How would the WebView be in a loading state if it's not rendered in the tree? You would have to hide it with opacity or height set to zero on the containing component. onPageFinished, do the logic to swap visibility.

Answer (score -1):

I used A stack in flutter.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    isLoading = true;
    super.initState();
  }
```

in the build method

```
     Stack(
        children: [
          isLoading ? Loading() : Container(),
          Container(
            child: Flex(
              direction: Axis.vertical,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: InAppWebView(
                    contextMenu: contextMenu,
                    initialUrl: url,

                    onLoadSop: (InAppWebViewController controller, url) {
                      setState(() {
                        isLoading = false;
                      });
                    },
                  )
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```