# Flutter Add Live Stream Video from Ustream

Tags: flutter

Hey guys am relatively new to flutter and would like to embed live stream from Ustream on my flutter app. Can Anyone help me on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61455137/6523474) to video content on how to setup youtube/vimeo on flutter. You can simply replace the link with ustream link and itll work. Hope this helps someone