# Flutter: Loading an IFrame from WebView on windows desktop app

Tags: flutter, dart

I found many packages for android, ios or web application's, but zero for windows desktop application. Is there any solution to use IFrame on win desktop application?

I need to go ona my desire page and find IFrame in my desire element. Copy paste to my application. And run program.

this link is just an example, that postet solutions are not for windows desktop application: [Flutter: Loading an IFrame from WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54464853/flutter-loading-an-iframe-from-webview)

Comment: Try with these packages: https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_webview_window https://pub.dev/packages/webview_windows

Answer (score 0):

Add the webview_windows package to your pubspec.yaml file:

Run `flutter pub add webview_windows` to fetch the package.

Create a WebViewWindows widget and provide the desired URL containing the IFrame:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_windows/webview_windows.dart';

class MyWebView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('WebView Demo'),
      ),
      body: WebViewWindows(
        initialUrl: 'https://example.com', // Replace with your IFrame URL
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```